# I had a question on Stack Overflow somebody migrated to Super User

Tags: discussion, profile-page, site-crossover, superuser

I had a question on Stack Overflow that somebody migrated to Super User. I am OK with that, but the migrator didn't check to see if I have a user account for the destination site or how the actual conversation will continue!

I recognize the need to organize this question and have on right place for next person to find it, given this huge community, but we should not lose the main objective of letting people find answers.

I think that we should give at least a few days/hours to the original creator to migrate it, rather then just doing it.

Now I have login to Stack Overflow but not to Super User. Why is the same login not working there? It is not allowing me to select Stack Overflow as one of the login options, and my profile in Stack Overflow does not allow me to add new sites like Super User.

Comment: Why not simply create an account on Super User once you see the question has been moved? It's a trivial process if you already have a Stack Overflow account.

Comment: @Sendi_t Pro tip, insulting people for downvoting your question is going to attract a lot more downvotes, it is not in fact a good way to prevent or reverse downvotes

Comment: I had no intention of insulting him, instead of recognizing the issue, he tells me the work-around.. I have other reasons not to create the yet another account.. besides that all I did it asked a q.. if he know the answer . kindly let me know.. what is the point in giving -ve points ?

Comment: Downvotes on meta are a bit different than on the main sites. On meta, downvotes don't cost anything and don't harm you in an way. They often get cast to show agreement or disagreement with a suggested action/perceived fault or proposed feature request.

Comment: You didn't care to make sure your question was on topic, yet you insist others must ensure you have an account on the site where it is migrated? You're absolutely right.  Your question should have been downvoted, closed and deleted instead of migrated.  Also, "but we should not loose main objective of letting ppl find answers" GFY.

Comment: _Why same login is not working there?_

Even though they are all Stack Exchange communities, they are still separate sites. There are 141 Stack Exchange sites; it doesn't make sense to assume that someone who wants a Stack Overflow account also wants an account for 140 other SE sites.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is - you asked a question, it was moved to the most appropriate site for it, it got an answer. **What are you complaining about?** Your login issues are totally separate to the migration process.

Comment: @Will `You didn't care to make sure your question was on topic, yet you insist others must ensure you have an account on the site where it is migrated? ' -- cant believe whats happening today -- are you saying if one made a mistake you would do the same? all I asked is -- to notify user and give at least a day? or hours ? to fix ? is it too much to ask ?  -- also as we are all software professionals .. the migration could have been prevented by the site application it self.. user/mod didn't have to do nothing...  -- did you think of this view?

Comment: Sendi_t, I don't think it's even possible for a user to migrate their own question. You'd have to delete it and re-post it and deleting a question counts against you (after a certain number of deletions the system will prevent you from asking). It's actually better for someone else to just migrate it.

Comment: @Sendi_t a day is **ages** in internet time. If we left bad-fit questions on e.g. SO for that long they would likely attract large numbers of downvotes and be closed or even deleted. People also "wander off" after asking and may not return within an hour. Prompt migration is the best thing for everyone; membership of all SE sites is easy and free, so not having an account really isn't a barrier for more than a minute or two.

Comment: @BSMP -- this topic has gone in wrong direction, the question actually is about " Is there a way to have same login across multiple stackoverflow brand of sites?" before creating yet another login-- is there an easier way? so i can seamlessly go across these sites?"    -- one can expect it as if a question can migrate with same username  across sites-- one would expect that the login can be migrated -- no? -- am I the only one thinking like this?  -- and it took completely different direction.

Comment: plus it is amazing to see  that almost everyone (who voted ) on this page/question has a same view (of  disagreeing) -- even though it should have 50% either way probability of voting..  but results showing that there is not even a single person visited that has same/similar q. cross their mind..    (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290584/why-are-stack-overflow-and-super-user-two-different-sites?rq=1)

Comment: @Sendi_t *"it should have 50% either way probability of voting"* - I don't think you've understood probability **at all**. Having two options does not necessarily mean both are equally likely, particularly when opinions are involved.

Comment: @Sendi_t *"the question actually is about " Is there a way to have same login across multiple stackoverflow brand of sites?""* - that was (and still is) **not clear** from its content. There already **is** a way - my SE network account is linked to several others (see http://stackexchange.com/users/3597514/jonrsharpe?tab=accounts) simply by logging in to those sites with the same credentials and clicking the button to connect the new account. If you've had trouble with that, please be specific about the issue (what did you try, what happened, etc.).

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- in my view the question is should we have cross site login or not -- in unbiased env. you would have ans Yes/NO - which both should have 50% prob.

Comment: @Sendi_t that's a ridiculous assumption. What on earth makes you think that asking people for their opinions could **ever** be described as an *"unbiased env."*?! Would you expect 50:50 split for and against legalising murder? Are you surprised every time an election doesn't end up with equal votes for every candidate? And, again, **we do have cross site login**.

Comment: Are you comparing legalizing murder with election results or this voting for this q?

Comment: @Sendi_t both and either. My point is that it's absurd to assert that a community should be split 50:50 on **any** given issue. Some things are very close, some things are a clear slam dunk. If you'd asked *"should we have a cross-site login?"*, I'm sure that would have been very popular (because, and I'm kind of tired of saying this, **we already do**, and AFAIK nobody's asked to get rid of it). It might get still downvotes, though, on the basis that **why are you asking this, when we *already* have cross-site logins?** You still haven't told us **what problem you're having with using them**.

Comment: _I think that we should give at least a few days/hours to the original creator to migrate **it**_ - It wasn't clear that by _it_ you meant your login and not the question itself. In any case, the answer from Brad below explains how to have the same login for both sites. You just have to sign up for that site using your existing login for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 18):

To expand on my comment, if you have a question migrated to another site, you are presented with a direct link to the new location of that question. Once you visit the site, you can create an account there quickly by clicking the "log in" link at the top of the page.

If you log in with your Stack Exchange account (the same one as your Stack Overflow account), you can create a new account there in a couple of clicks that's associated with your Stack Overflow one.  Then you can continue interacting with your migrated question there, and both accounts will be associated together.

As to why we like to migrate questions early: if a question is worth migrating, we want to get it into the right place as quickly as we can. This allows it to get proper attention from experts, and makes sure that it doesn't waste the time of those reading it on the original site. It also helps to avoid downvotes for being out of place. It's all in an effort to help you get a good answer to your question and to make sure no one's time is wasted.

Comment: look you have 100k experience..not everyone is like you.. as a "pro" member you should be considerate.. I didn't even know that I should put "user profile" kind of q. here -- I could have just asked it on stackoverflow and one of you might have moved it here --- but I did my reasearch -learning form my previous q. and found a right place to ask--- so I am putting my efforts --- but to give -ve vote -- even when you dont have a solution --  I dont think it is fair

Comment: @Sendi_t You're reading too much into downvotes. Stop taking them so personally.. Downvotes are going to happen, use them constructively by trying to figure out what caused them (without being ugly in the comments)

Comment: Also you should realize that b/c of your "unrelated comments" now this q. has gone wrong direction, it is not going to address a real question..

Comment: @Sendi_t - I didn't downvote your question, and am just trying to help you out by pointing out where you can go to do this and why we migrate things early. I believe that others are downvoting based on your suggestion of "I think we should at lest give a few days/hours to original creator to migrate it?" Downvotes on Meta are also used to express disagreement with proposals, and people apparently disagree with that suggestion. As stated above, there are good reasons for wanting to migrate things early, rather than having them hang around the site for a while.